# Create custom data type in Python

Tags: python

Hopefully the title isn't too misleading, I'm not sure the best way to phrase my question.

I'm trying to create a `(X, Y)` coordinate data type in Python. Is there a way to create a "custom data type" so that I have an object with a value, but also some supporting attributes?

So far I've made this simple class:

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tuple = (x, y)
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
>>> p = Point(4, 5)
>>>
>>> my_x = p.x    # can access the `x` attribute with "dot syntax"
>>>
>>> my_tuple = p  # or can access the tuple value directly
                  # without needing to do `.tuple`, as if the `tuple`
                  # attribute is the "default" attribute for the object
```

**NOTE** I'm not trying to simply display the tuple, I know I can do that with the `__repr__` method

In a way, I'm trying to create a very simplified `numpy.ndarray`, because the `ndarray`s are a datatype that have their own attributes. I tried looking thru the `numpy` source to see how this is done, but it was way over my head, haha.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it working for you? If all you want to do is access x and y, ..., you're there. Its uncommon to also set the `tuple` attribute because then you have to worry about keeping data in sync if x, y or the tuple itself change. Do you want to perform operations on the class as a whole, or just have a convenient place to park x and y? Are these mutable or immutable? As stands, the class already does what you want. We need to know what problem you are having.

Comment: Regarding `my_tuple = p` accessing "tuple directly without needing to do  `.tuple`", I can't think of a way this is possible. The statement `my_tuple = p` defines a new reference to an object, which could be any python object in principle.

Comment: [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) may be what you want. Review it, and let us know how it _doesn't_ work for you.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem - `namedtuple` does it. You can access its values as `p.x` or `p[0]`. It even works with `isinstance(p, tuple)`. You don't need the `my_tuple = p` part, though. As you say, all that does is add a ref count to the existing object.

Comment: @tdelaney good point about the syncing issues, I hadn’t considered that. The `Point` was a somewhat simplified example of what I’m dealing with, but overall I think I’m over-engineering this piece in attempt to make my code cleaner (which has backfired haha). I think I’ll try to use the namedtuple as suggest by @Thomas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to do with the tuple. `p` will always be an instance of `Point`. What you intend to do there won't work.

If you just don't want to use the dot notation, you could use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or a [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) instead of a class. Then cast their instances to a tuple using [`tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple) and [`astuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.astuple).

---

Using a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) and [`tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple("Point", ["x", "y"])

p = Point(4, 5)

x = p.x
y = p.y

xy = p  # xy = tuple(p) not necessary since namedtuple is already a tuple
```

Note: `namedtuple` is immutable, i.e. you can't change `x` and `y`.

---

Using a [`dataclasses.dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) and [`dataclasses.astuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.astuple):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, astuple

@dataclass
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int
    
p = Point(4, 5)

x = p.x
y = p.y

xy = astuple(p)
```

Comment: Great answer but you don't need `xy = tuple(p)` with `namedtuple`. It already is a tuple (or at least a subclass there-of).

Answer (score 6):

**Python 3.12+**

[PEP 695](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/) introduces a new, more compact and explicit way to create generic classes and functions. In addition, the PEP introduces a new way to declare type aliases using the `type` statement, which creates an instance of TypeAliasType. As a result, you can do this:

```py
type Point = tuple[float, float]
# or
type Point[T] = tuple[T, T] # more generic
```

For example, you can use it like this:

```py
type Point = tuple[int, int]
p: Point = (0,0)
print(p) # (0,0)

p = (4,5) # re-assign Point p
print(p[0]) # 4, your "x" 
print(p[1]) # 5, your "y"
```

Depending on your use case, this answer may not be relevant.